# Php не обрабатывает аргумент

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Написал простейший код

```
<?php
echo "Hello, $name";
?>
```

Но при вводе в url: `test.ru/index.php?name=Vasilii`
на станице отображается только `Hello`, 
Пробовал выносить переменную из кавычек, т.е. `"Hello, ". $name` и тоже не помогло. То же самое с формами, не забирает данные. Использую denwer.

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/globals

Comment: И так пробовал, читайте внимательно.

Comment: Кстати, настоятельно рекомендую сменить учебник на изданный в этом веке.

Comment: @Ипатьев Премного благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные, которые поступают из вне через запросы GET (через адресную строку) или POST, доступны через массивы [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php) и [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), соответственно.

Однако, перед тем как работать с этими массивами необходимо проверить наличие в них данных с помощью функции [isset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php). Это застрахует от многих ошибок.

Пример для Вашего случая:

```
if (isset($_GET['name']))
{
    echo "Hello,".$_GET['name'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался. Учебник 2003 года, я думал, может с интерпретатором что-то не так.

Answer (score 0):

Все параметры переданные через URL попадают в массив `$_GET[]`. В Вашем случае `$name` будет доступен через `$_GET['name']`. 
Параметры переданные через форму попадают в `$_POST`, если в форме указан `method=post` соответственно.

Разница в типах заключается в максимальной размере данных, которые возможно передать. Для метода GET это 255 символов(ограничение связано с максимальной возможной длинной URL)